# Time complexity of tape equilibirum

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, complexity

As per the instructions on this [Tape Equlibrium-Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/tape_equilibrium/)

I've written the code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TapeEqulibrium {
  int main(int[] array) {
    int minimumDiff = 100000;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int differnce = Math.abs(Arrays.stream(array, 0, i).sum() - Arrays.stream(array, i, array.length).sum());
        minimumDiff = differnce < minimumDiff ? differnce : minimumDiff;
    }
    return minimumDiff;
   }
}
```

On submission, I have got correct answers for all test cases. But It says that the time complexity is O(n*n)and taking more than 6.00 seconds. while writing I thought that it falls under time complexity of O(n) or something (as I don't know much about that). So I need to know how to calculate the time complexity of this code.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Here we review working code to make it better (faster, leaner, more secure/readable/maintainable). While a reviewer commenting on the time complexity of your code is likely (since you seem to exceed some time-limit, in which case you also might consider adding the tag [tag:time-limit-exceeded]), note that you may receive different answers as well (all questions here are by definition open-ended). Have a look at our [help] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inner loop contains:

```
int differnce = Math.abs(Arrays.stream(array, 0, i).sum() - Arrays.stream(array, i, array.length).sum());
```

That does (i-0) operations for first sum and (array.length-i) for second, for a total of array.length-i+i-0=array.length. As the size of input is `n=array.length` that really gives O(n*n). Replacing for-loops with Streams doesn't improve complexity, only hides it a bit.